# Want to deserialize XML to object in a specific way

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to do deserialize XML to model.
I have, for example:

```
<A>
    <B id=1></B>
    <B id=2></B>
    <B id=3></B>
</A>
```

Is it possible to grab id's of B without creating model B?
So I want to have something like this in the end:

```
public class A {
    [XmlAttribute(B/@id)]
    public List<int> ids { get; set; }
}
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the ISerializable interface to add custom serialization / deserialization.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675.aspx

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject : ISerializable 
{
  public int n1;
  public int n2;
  public String str;

  public MyObject()
  {
  }

  protected MyObject(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    n1 = info.GetInt32("i");
    n2 = info.GetInt32("j");
    str = info.GetString("k");
  }
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, 
SerializationFormatter =true)]

public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    info.AddValue("i", n1);
    info.AddValue("j", n2);
    info.AddValue("k", str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx. It'll work, I'm pretty sure, but it's too complex for my situation. It's an answer, but unfortunately, I'm unable to score it, because my rep is lower than 15. :(

Comment: I shick with your decigion in the end. Thx! ;)

Comment: no problem, hope you get on OK. I think what you need to do in your get object data is to take all the B nodes, Add to a list, then call info.AddValue("B", yourlist);